# Error en proyecto Typescript

Tags: typescript

Estoy creando un proyecto con TypeScript, pero al compilar después de haber me da el siguiente error:

```
Cannot write file 'C/ruta/de/mi/proyecto/lib/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

Este es mi tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2021"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.d.ts"],
  "include": ["lib/**/*.ts", "bin/*.ts"]<
}
```

Y mi estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

```
.
|   .gitignore
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   tsconfig.json
|   
+---bin
|       builder.ts
|       
+---lib
|   |   index.ts
|   |   
|
```

¿A que se debe este error?